# Parsing XML into a returnable multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, xml, multidimensional-array

I have tried this a few different ways, returning the SimpleXML object directly, and now running through it, turning it into a multidimensional array, but nothing seems to work, as soon as I try to return it to another function, it just blanks. I must be missing something here, but for the life of me I just cannot see what it is.

```
    public function getSettings() {
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('SETTINGS.xml');
        $settings = array();
        foreach ($xml->settings->page as $page) {
            $settings[$page->title] = array("Navbar" => $page->navbar, "Elements" => array());
            foreach ($page->element as $element){
                array_push($settings[$page->title]["Elements"],
                        ["Name" => $element->name,
                        "File" => $element->location,
                        "Style" => $element->style]);
            }
        }

        return $settings;
    }
```

---

SETTINGS.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <settings>

    <page>
        <title>Login</title>
        <navbar></navbar>
        <element>
            <name>Login</name>
            <location>Login.php</location>
            <style>Style.css</style>
        </element>
    </page>
    <page>
        <title>Dashboard</title>
        <navbar>Navbar.php</navbar>
        <element>
            <name>Recent Punishments Table</name>
            <location>RecentPunishments.php</location>
            <style>Style.css</style>
        </element>
    </page>
    </settings>
```

Comment: simplexml does not see root element. change to `foreach ($xml->page as $page)`

Comment: Remember to explicitly cast anything you're reading with SimpleXML to string/int/etc, you'll run into some weird behaviour otherwise.

Comment: @iainn  this is excessive - https://eval.in/560582

Comment: You can get away without casting them if you're just echoing them to screen, since the __tostring method will do it automatically. If you're doing anything more complicated (calculations, etc) then not casting will have undesired side-effects. https://eval.in/560602